# Single conditional select query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have the following table say filenames.

```
filename   flag
fileA       1
fileB       0
fileC       0
fileD       1
fileA       1
```

I want all distinct filenames from this table AND
If the flag is 1 for any file name, i want that file name to be replaced with 4 file names as FilaA_part_1, FilaA_part_2, FilaA_part_3, FilaA_part_4.

output should be

```
FilaA_part_1
FilaA_part_2
FilaA_part_3
FilaA_part_4
fileB      
fileC
FilaD_part_1
FilaD_part_2
FilaD_part_3
FilaD_part_4
```

I am able to achieve this with temp table. I want to know if it is possible with single select query.

I could get as far as

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN FLAG=1 THEN FILENAME + '_part_1' 
ELSE FILENAME END
FROM FILENAMES
```

Comment: You have 2 times `fileA` is this correct?

Comment: declare @i varchar(10)
set @i =1
create table #temp ([filename] varchar(50))
while (@i <= 4)
begin
insert into #temp([filename])
SELECT distinct  case when flag = 1 then [filename]+'Part_'+@i else [filename] end [filename] 
FROM
(  
 SELECT 'fileA'    [filename] ,  1 flag
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'fileB',       0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'fileC',       0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'fileD',       1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'fileA' ,      0
)BASE
set @i= @i+1
end

select distinct [filename] from #temp

drop table #temp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a union should do:

```
SELECT FILENAME
FROM FILENAMES
WHERE FLAG = 0
UNION 
SELECT FILENAME + '_part_1'
FROM FILENAMES
WHERE FLAG = 1
UNION 
SELECT FILENAME + '_part_2'
FROM FILENAMES
WHERE FLAG = 1
UNION 
SELECT FILENAME + '_part_3'
FROM FILENAMES
WHERE FLAG = 1
UNION 
SELECT FILENAME + '_part_4'
FROM FILENAMES
WHERE FLAG = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this should swork in sql server 2000

```
SELECT filename + '_part' + num
FROM   Yourtable
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT '_1' num
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT '_2'
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT '_3'
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT '_4') A
WHERE  flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT filename
FROM   Yourtable B
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Yourtable A
                   WHERE  a.filename = b.filename
                          AND a.flag = 1)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d24c0b/1)

Comment: I realized that I misread the question and therefor removed my comment. I wrongly assumed that filename where the primary key. One might wonder what it means for a file to both have a flag and not?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i varchar(10) 
set @i =1 
create table #temp ([filename] varchar(50)) 
while (@i <= 4) 
begin 
    insert into #temp([filename]) 
    SELECT distinct 
           case when flag = 1 then [filename]+'Part_'+@i 
                              else [filename] 
           end [filename] 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 'fileA'[filename] ,1 flag 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'fileB',0 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'fileC', 0 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'fileD', 1 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'fileA' , 0 
    ) BASE 
    set @i= @i+1 
end 
select distinct [filename] from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT filename + '_part' + num
FROM   FILENAMES
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT '_1' num
               UNION ALL
               SELECT '_2'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT '_3'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT '_4') A
WHERE  flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT filename
FROM   FILENAMES B
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   FILENAMES A
               WHERE  a.filename = b.filename
                      AND a.flag = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a exact output which you post in Q i hope this will help you

```
declare @temp table
(filenames nvarchar(44),   flag int
)
insert into @temp values ('fileA',      1)
insert into @temp values ('fileB',      0)
insert into @temp values ('fileC',      0)
insert into @temp values ('fileD',      1)
insert into @temp values ('fileA',      0);

; with cte as(
select filenames,flag from @temp t1 where not exists (select 1 from @temp t2 where t1.filenames = t2.filenames AND t2.flag = 1)
union 
select filenames + '_part_1',flag from @temp where flag = 1
union                       
select filenames + '_part_2',flag from @temp where flag = 1
union                       
select filenames + '_part_3',flag from @temp where flag = 1
union                       
select filenames + '_part_4',flag from @temp where flag = 1)

select * FROM cte
```